# Exception when trying to get the chrome console logs

Tags: c#, selenium, exception, null

This is my code:

```
using FirstTestCase.PageObjectMethods;
using NUnit.Framework;
using OpenQA.Selenium;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome;
using System;
using System.Threading;

namespace FirstTestCase
{

[TestFixture]
class TestClassLog

{
    class NUnitTest
    {
        private IWebDriver _driver;
        

        [TestCase(TestName = "test")]
        public void Initialize()
        {
            
            ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
            options.SetLoggingPreference(LogType.Browser, LogLevel.All);
            

            var driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
            driver.Manage().Window.Maximize();
            driver.Url = "test.test";
            var homePage = new HomePage(driver);

            homePage.SignIn().Click();                
            homePage.Email("email");
            homePage.Password("pw");
            homePage.LogIn();
            var logs = driver.Manage().Logs.GetLog(LogType.Browser);
            foreach (var log in logs)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(log.ToString());
            }
      }
```

On the line `var logs = driver.Manage().Logs.GetLog(LogType.Browser);` i get the following exception: `System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'`

I've broken the line into 3 different ones:

```
            var logs = driver.Manage();
            var logs1 = logs.Logs;
            var logs2 = logs1.GetLog(LogType.Browser);
            foreach (var log in logs2)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(log.ToString());
            }
```

and the same exception happens on `var logs2 = logs1.GetLog(LogType.Browser);`

I have no idea why I am getting it, i can't seem to find what I am doing wrong

Answer (score 0):

Your code is correct but this is currently not working in Selenium.WebDriver 3.141.0

If you absolutely need this working, you are going to have to upgrade to the beta version of Selenium.Webdriver. I confirmed this is working in beta4

https://www.nuget.org/packages/Selenium.WebDriver/4.0.0-beta4

Comment: Hey! Thank you for your reply. I did update and started working. Unfortunately, i am not getting the entire console log of the duration of the test. I will need to investigate more